# How can I integrate a mixins.less file with my other less files when using ASP MVC4, VS2012 and Web Essentials?

Tags: css, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, less

I have so far set up multiple .less files and when I save them these are compiled to .css files. When I publish all the css are brought together in a bundle.

But now I would like to start using a mixins file.  How can I integrate this and make it available to all the .less files? Is this possible with Web Essentials and ASP MVC4 ? Most importantly I want to be sure all the bundling and mimification will still work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your mixins in a separate file and reference it using @import

```
@import url('mixins.less');
```